# OpenCV Android with nonfree package (SURF)

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing, android-ndk

I'm trying to make app that can detect similarity in pictures in Android. I'm trying to do it with OpenCV and with `SurfFeatureDetector`. But now in OpenCV it's not package `nonfree` and I'm trying to go according to this tutorial
https://sites.google.com/site/wghsite/technical-notes/sift_surf_opencv_android but I'm getting problem:

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type make: ***
>   [obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libmixed_sample.so] Error 1    appname         C/C++
>
> Problem recipe for target `obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libmixed_sample.so'
>   failed    appname     line 588, external location:
>   C:\NVPACK\android-ndk-r9d\build\core\build-binary.mk  C/C++
>
> Problem undefined reference to 'cv::SURF::SURF(double, int, int, bool,
>   bool)'    appname     line 54, external location:
>   C:\NVPACK\android-ndk-r9d\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.6\prebuilt\windows\arm-linux-androideabi\bin\ld.exe:
>   .\obj\local\armeabi-v7a\objs-debug\mixed_sample\jni_part.o: in
>   function
>   Java_sk_appname_MyOpenCVActivity_MojaSkuska:jni\jni_part.cpp  C/C++
>
> Problem undefined reference to 'VTT for cv::SURF' appname     line 107,
>   external location:
>   C:\NVPACK\android-ndk-r9d\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.6\prebuilt\windows\arm-linux-androideabi\bin\ld.exe:
>   .\obj\local\armeabi-v7a\objs-debug\mixed_sample\jni_part.o: in
>   function
>   cv::SURF::~SURF():sdk\native\jni\include\opencv2\nonfree\features2d.hpp   C/C++
>
> Problem undefined reference to 'vtable for cv::SURF'  appname     line
>   107, external location:
>   C:\NVPACK\android-ndk-r9d\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.6\prebuilt\windows\arm-linux-androideabi\bin\ld.exe:
>   .\obj\local\armeabi-v7a\objs-debug\mixed_sample\jni_part.o: in
>   function
>   cv::SURF::~SURF():sdk\native\jni\include\opencv2\nonfree\features2d.hpp   C/C++
>   Problem

I'm really desperate, I'm trying for 3 days make this work with a lot of tutorials but nothing is working. This is **Android.mk:**

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

OPENCV_CAMERA_MODULES:=on
OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on
#include ./sdk/native/jni/OpenCV-tegra3.mk
include ./sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk

LOCAL_MODULE    := mixed_sample
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := jni_part.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS +=  -llog -ldl

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)


#pridane 

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := nonfree_prebuilt
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libnonfree.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := opencv_java_prebuilt
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libopencv_java.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

I have no idea if I have properly inserted libraries - but in /libs/armeabi-v7a there are builded nonfree libraries. Also when I do import in jni_part.cpp (where I want to use SURF) `#include <opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp>`, it's OK without erros. Please, help me, if You could give me any advice it would be really great. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem was with **Android.mk.**

It wasn't possible to add 2 LOCAL_SRC_FILES (I don't know why, in this I'm really noob).

So this was final version:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

OPENCV_CAMERA_MODULES:=on
OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on
include ./sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk

LOCAL_MODULE    := mixed_sample
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := jni_part.cpp \
    nonfree_init.cpp \
 precomp.cpp \
 sift.cpp \
 surf.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS +=  -llog -ldl
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES:= ./sdk/native/jni/include
LOCAL_MODULE    := nonfree
LOCAL_CFLAGS    := -Werror -O3 -ffast-math
LOCAL_LDLIBS    += -llog
```

It was really weird problem, but now everything seems to work just fine.